# Pandas new column with same value for certain rows

Tags: pandas, geometry, point, geopandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```py
Sezione         Indirizzo                   geometry
6              Via Carlo e Valeria Jülg, 9  None
6              Via Carlo e Valeria Jülg, 9  None
...            ...                          ...
3              Via di Revolta, 4            None
3              Via di Revolta, 4           None
```

and a dictionary `addresses` like  this:

```py
{
 3: 0    POINT (11.10417 46.01877) Name: geometry, dtype: geometry,
 
 6: 0    POINT (11.12534 46.07222) Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

I would like to assign to the geometry column the corresponding values for all the rows that have the same `Sezione`:

```py
Sezione         Indirizzo                   geometry
6              Via Carlo e Valeria Jülg, 9  POINT (11.12534 46.07222)
6              Via Carlo e Valeria Jülg, 9  POINT (11.12534 46.07222)
...            ...                          ...
3              Via di Revolta, 4            POINT (11.10417 46.01877)
3              Via di Revolta, 4            POINT (11.10417 46.01877)
```

I tried the following but applies the value to  the  first row and doesn't continue.

```py
for i in range(1, len(addresses)):
    df.loc[df.Sezione == i, "geometry"] = addresses[i]
```

trying assigning directly obviously fails for warnings. Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with a nice `lambda`

```py
df["geometry"] = df["Sezione"].apply(lambda x: addresses[x])
```